# Use proximity sensor without turning the screen off

Tags: iphone

This is a long shot, but does anyone know a way to avoid the automatic screen blanking when using the proximity sensor (UIDevice.proximityMonitoringEnabled & proximityState)?

Answer (score 1):

UIDevice only allows you to monitor the proximity sensor state and handle it within your app. You cannot control the blackening of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick to temporary disable screen turn off

```
 UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
 [device setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
```

But current public API do not allow to use proximity sensor without blacking out the screen. Any one have solution for this?